# Reading an input file with 6 columns

Tags: python

Consider this code where I read an input file with 6 columns (0-5):

1. Initialize a variable `history_ends` to 5000.
2. When the `column0` value (i.e. job[0] < 5000) I add 5000 lines of the input file in a list (`historyjobs`) else the rest of the lines until the eof in another list (`targetjobs`).
3. All the `historyjobs` list all contents in `item3`, `item4`, `item5` is equal to `targetjobs`. First list `item3`, `item4`, `item5` when this condition is satisfied. Add those `historyjobs` all `item1` to list `listsub`.
4. Find the running mean of the items in `listsub` and reverse the list, store it in list

   1. Check the condition if items in `listsub > a*0.9` which satisfies the condition. Stores the result items in list `condsub`.
5. Reopen the `inputfile` and check whether `column0` is equal to items in `condsub`. If it satisfies, then add the `column1` to a list `condrun`.
6. Open the output file and write in `colum0` the second item of first list in `targetjobs` i.e. `j`, in `column1`, write the average of list `condrun`, `column2` is `(j-avg)/j`, `column3` is the maximum item in list `condrun`, `column4` is the minimum item in list `condrun`, `column5` is the length of the list `condrun`, the last four columns is based on the condition.
7. I am repeating the whole procedure using a `while` loop by assigning the variable `historyends` to the next item `int(targetjobs[1][0])`.

```
from __future__ import division
import itertools

history_begins = 1; history_ends = 5000; n = 0; total = 0
historyjobs = []; targetjobs = []
listsub = []; listrun = []; listavg = [] ; F = [] ; condsub = [] ;condrun = [] ;mlistsub = []; a = []

def check(inputfile):

      f = open(inputfile,'r') #reads the inputfile
      lines = f.readlines()
      for line in lines:
          job = line.split()
          if( int(job[0]) < history_ends ): #if the column0 is less then history_ends(i,e 5000 initially)
                historyjobs.append(job) #historyjobs list contains all the lines from the list whose column1 < history_ends
          else:
                targetjobs.append(job) #historyjobs list contains all the lines from the list whose column1 > history_ends  
      k = 0           
      for i, element in enumerate(historyjobs):
          if( (int(historyjobs[i][3]) == int(targetjobs[k][3])) and (int(historyjobs[i][4]) == int(targetjobs[k][4])) and (int(historyjobs[i][5]) == int(targetjobs[k][5])) ): #historyjobs list all contents in column3,column4,column5 is equal to targetjobs first list column3,column4,column5

                 listsub.append(historyjobs[i][1]) #when if condition true add those historyjobs column1 to list listsub               

def runningMean(iterable):
"""A generator, yielding a cumulative average of its input."""
  num = 0
  denom = 0
  for x in iterable:
    num += x
    denom += 1
    yield num / denom

def newfun(results):
  results.reverse() # put them back in regular order
  for value, average in results:
    a.append(value)
  return a #to return the value   

def runcheck(subseq):
      f = open('newfileinput','r') #again read the same inputfile
      lines = f.readlines()
      for line in lines:
          job = line.split()
          for i, element in enumerate(subseq):
             if(int(job[1]) == int(subseq[i])): # if the column1 value of the inputfile becomes equal to list obtained
                  condrun.append(str(job[2])) #return the value of column2 which satisfies the if condition
      return condrun


def listcreate(condrun,condsub):
     f1 = open('outputfile','a') #outputfile to append the result
     s = map(int,condrun)
     j = int(targetjobs[0][2])
     targetsub = int(targetjobs[0][1])
     if(condsub != []):
      try:
       convertsub = int(condsub[-1])
       a=sum(s)/len(s)
       c=max(s)
       d=min(s)
       e1=abs(j-a)
       er1=e1/j
       g=len(s)
       h=abs(convertsub-targetsub)
       f1.write(str(j))
       f1.write('\t')
       f1.write('\t')
       f1.write(str(round(a,2)))
       f1.write('\t')
       f1.write('\t')
       f1.write(str(round(er1,3)))
       f1.write('\t')
       f1.write('\t')
       f1.write(str(c))
       f1.write('\t')
       f1.write('\t')
       f1.write(str(d))
       f1.write('\t')
       f1.write('\t')
       f1.write(str(g))
       f1.write('\t')
       f1.write('\t')
       f1.write(str(h))
       f1.write('\t')
       f1.write("\t")
       if (float(er1) < 0.20):
         f1.write("good")
         f1.write("\t")
       else :
         f1.write("bad")
         f1.write("\t")
       if (float(er1) < 0.30):
         f1.write("good")
         f1.write("\t")
       else :
         f1.write("bad")
         f1.write("\t")
       if (float(er1) < 0.40):
         f1.write("good")
         f1.write("\t")
       else :
         f1.write("bad")
         f1.write("\t")
       if (float(er1) < 0.50):
         f1.write("good")
         f1.write("\n")
       else :
         f1.write("bad")
         f1.write("\n")
      except ZeroDivisionError :
       print 'dem 0'
     else:
       print '0'
       f1.close() 

def new():
 global history_ends
 while 1: #To repeat the process untill the EOF(end of input file)

    check('newfileinput') #First function call
    if(len(targetjobs) != 1):
     history_ends = int(targetjobs[1][0]) #initialize historyends to targetjobs second lines first item
     mlistsub = map(int,listsub)
     results = list(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x[0] > 0.9 * x[1],
                               itertools.izip(reversed(mlistsub),
                                              runningMean(reversed(mlistsub)))))#call runningmean function & check the condition
     condsub = newfun(results) #function to reverse back the result    
     condrun=runcheck(condsub) #functionto match & return the value
     listcreate(condrun,condsub) #function to write result to output file     
     del condrun[0:len(condrun)]#to delete the values in list
     del condsub[0:len(condsub)]#to delete the values in list
     del listsub[0:len(listsub)]#to delete the values in list
     del targetjobs[0:len(targetjobs)]#to delete the values in list
     del historyjobs[0:len(historyjobs)]#to delete the values in list
    else:
      break


def main():

   new()      

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The sample input file (whole file contains 200,000 lines):

> ```
>  1    0   9227    1152    34  2
>  2    111 7622    1120    34  2
>  3    68486   710 1024    14  2
>  6    265065  3389    800 22  2
>  7    393152  48438   64  132 3
>  8    412251  46744   64  132 3
>  9    430593  50866   256 95  4
>  10   430730  10770   256 95  4
>  11   433750  12701   256 14  3
>  12   437926  2794    64  34  2
>  13   440070  43  32  96  3
> ```

The sample output file contents:

> ```
> 930       1389.14     0.494       3625        977     7       15      bad bad bad good
> 4348      1331.75     0.694       3625        930     8       164     bad bad bad bad
> 18047     32237.0     0.786       61465       17285       3       325774      bad bad bad bad
> 1607      1509.0      0.061       1509        1509        1       6508        good    good    good    good
> 304       40.06       0.868       80      32      35      53472       bad bad bad bad
> 7246      7247.0      0.0     7247        7247        1       9691        good    good    good    good
> 95        1558.0      15.4        1607        1509        2       2148        bad bad bad bad
> 55        54.33       0.012       56      53      3       448142      good    good    good    good
> 31        76.38       1.464       392     35      13      237152      bad bad bad bad
> 207       55.0        0.734       55      55      1       370     bad bad bad bad
> ```

If anyone could suggest some changes to help make the code run faster, that'd be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Comments about coding style:

- inconsistent indentation makes the code harder to read
- preferred indentation width in python is 4 spaces

Why is the question tagged python3 ? This is python2 code.

---

```
history_begins = 1; history_ends = 5000; n = 0; total = 0
historyjobs = []; targetjobs = []
listsub = []; listrun = []; listavg = [] ; F = [] ; condsub = [] ;condrun = [] ;mlistsub = []; a = []
```

There are variables defined here that aren't actually used in the script, and global variables shouldn't have one-letter names.

---

```
f = open(inputfile,'r') #reads the inputfile
```

No it doesn't, it just creates a file handle.

---

```
lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
```

However, this does read the file, it even loads it all in RAM at once, which is a waste because you don't actually need to, so do this instead:

```
for line in f:
```

---

```
f1.write(str(j))
f1.write('\t')
f1.write('\t')
...
if (float(er1) < 0.50):
    f1.write("good")
    f1.write("\n")
else:
    f1.write("bad")
    f1.write("\n")
```

That's redundant, factor it:

```
print(j, round(a,2), round(er1,3), c, d, g, h, sep='\t\t', end='\t\t', file=out)
w = ('bad', 'good')
print(w[er1 < .2], w[er1 < .3], w[er1 < .4], w[er1 < .5], sep='\t', file=out)
```

---

```
f = open('newfileinput','r') #again read the same inputfile
```

Why read the same file multiple times ? That's inefficient…

Answer (score 1):

OK, your code is a bit of a mess. I take it you are fairly new to python. Read the [python style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and stick to it. It will make it easier for people to read your code.

It is not easy to work out what you are trying to do here. As it stands the code doesn't run. However, here are some thoughts.

building on @Changaco's answer you can iterate through the file and process each row into integers like this.

```
def check(inputfile):
    f = open(inputfile,'r')
    for line in f:
        job = [int(s) for s in line.split()]
        ...
```

Doing the conversion once up front you can forget all the other int() conversions that clutter up your code. This includes removing the need for your mlistsub global entirely as far as I can tell as it seems to be an integer version of the listsub variable.

I suspect the following reference to job[0] should reference job[1 ] as it is column1, not column0 that you talk about in other comments.

```
if( int(job[0]) < history_ends ): #if the column0 is less then history_ends(i,e 5000 initially)
    ...
```

Also, brackets are not necessary and with the above int() conversion already done the line becomes

```
if job[1] < history_ends:
    ...
```

I would reduce the global variables to the absolute minimum (which is usually none). I cannot work out the detail but the only reason I can see to keep globals here would be if they are continually being appended to and this is not happening as far as I can tell.

For example, I think the global variable a = [] can be removed.

Your original function.

```
def newfun(results):
    results.reverse() # put them back in regular order
    for value, average in results:
        a.append(value)
    return a #to return the value
```

is called like this

```
 condsub = newfun(results) #function to reverse back the result
```

Aside from the terrible function name, this function seems to do very little. You could replace the function call with something like this

```
condsub = [value for value, average in reversed(results)] #reverse back the result
```

The following code

```
  k = 0           
  for i, element in enumerate(historyjobs):
      if( (int(historyjobs[i][3]) == int(targetjobs[k][3])) and (int(historyjobs[i][4]) == int(targetjobs[k][4])) and (int(historyjobs[i][5]) == int(targetjobs[k][5])) ): #historyjobs list all contents in column3,column4,column5 is equal to targetjobs first list column3,column4,column5
             listsub.append(historyjobs[i][1]) #when if condition true add those historyjobs column1 to list listsub
```

can be significantly cleaned up. There is no need to use enumerate() just to get the i variable. The idiomatic approach is to use 'for hjob in historyjobs:'. With the int() conversion already done you can replace the complicated comparison with a simple comparison of the slice of interest.

```
tjob = targetjobs[0]
for hjob in historyjobs:
    if hjob[3:6] == tjob[3:6]:
        listsub.append(hjob[1])
```

If I understand your intent, you can also create a simple list and return it from the function as a way to remove the listsub global variable.

```
result = []
tjob = targetjobs[0]
for hjob in historyjobs:
    if hjob[3:6] == tjob[3:6]:
        result.append(hjob[1])
return result
```

A conversion and filter operation can usually be achieved with a list comprehension. Something like this should do the trick.

```
return [hjob[1] for hjob in historyjobs if hjob[3:6] == targetjobs[0][3:6]]
```

Since you are deleting all your globals at the end of each loop, I am assuming you don't need them at all.

```
del condrun[0:len(condrun)]#to delete the values in list
del condsub[0:len(condsub)]#to delete the values in list
del listsub[0:len(listsub)]#to delete the values in list
del targetjobs[0:len(targetjobs)]#to delete the values in list
del historyjobs[0:len(historyjobs)]#to delete the values in list
```

This is not necessary if you return data from your functions as above and assign the result of the function calls to variables which are created in the scope of your new() function.

As I say, I'm not sure what your doing exactly here so I can't advise on the logic. If you can tidy it up a bit then I'm sure we can help you get to the bottom of it. My feeling is that the code can become much shorter and much clearer than your current version.